# TransX WCF and Multithreading

Tags: wcf

I have some queries about WCF and multithreading.
My plan is to place items onto the Thread Pool and for it to process messages from the MSMQ queue.
I also will be hosting WCF in WAS.

I am wondering how the threading will work at this point. For example messages will be picked up by the WCF binding to the MSMQ queue and I know that WAS will spin up the service as and when it requires to. But lets say if we have 100 messages to process (100 messages per second for example) - would these be delivered in a threaded way or in a single thread?

If in a threaded manner then how best to commit or abort transactions? Any special considerations?

Sorry for the questions - just need to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what "placing items onto the Thread Pool" does but on the WCF side, a service using the `netMsmqBinding` handles "calls" in a similar way as other WCF bindings. The difference is that a "call" is actually an MSMQ message in a queue.

This [article on netMsmqBinding](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2007-how-to-support-queued-calls-in-windows-communication-foundation-wcf/) gives a very clear explanation of how the binding works. If you configure the WCF service with its default InstanceContext setting (per call or per session depending on the .NET version), the service instances will pick up messages off the queue as-if they were a standard call each. There are setting in MSMQ and WCF that can affect this behavior to make the messages be processed sequentially but that's not the default.

Let WCF handle multi-threading for you by leaving the service set to per call (or per session) and for transactions, look at the code in [this sample in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751445.aspx) to see how to work with them.

Comment: Great. I had a suspicion of using the PerCall approach. I wont be using netMSMQBinding but integrated binding. Would this change the behavior?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the InstanceContext setting applies to a WCF service configured for msmqIntegrationBinding the same way as it applies to other bindings. The difference between msmqIntegrationBinding and netMsmqBinding is that in msmqIntegrationBinding configuration, the parameter for the operations are strongly typed MsmqMessage instances instead of a standard .NET type.

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much but wasnt sure. So conclusion here really is to use PerCall? and for transactions, I shouldnt worry to much as it would be as if it is invoking each request to the service (each request being 1 message which invokes the WCF Service). I wont be using PerSession at all AFAIK. It would be a matter of "WCF - here is an MSMQ message." - the Service then takes that and processes the msg I want, however I want and finally places it on 1 of 2 other outbound queues.

Comment: Yes, using per call for InstanceContext and leaving the ConcurrencyMode as the default Single will give you what you need. The ConcurrencyMode settings can confusing with some people thinking that Multiple is a "better preforming" setting but in actual use Multiple will cause problems if your service class has **any** module level variables (i.e. isn't thread safe) or isn't written to be reentrant.

Comment: I agree. But I can say that the service class will not have any module level variables but know how to make it thread safe (lock etc...). It will be a case of the MSMQ msg being given to the WCF service and then for it to process the business logic in a transactional way but want the requests to be using MT into the service and make it scalable and durable.